# Как создавать несколько таблиц на одном листе

Tags: excel

Нужна ваша помощь, как мне на одном листе создать несколько таблиц. Проблема в том что при изменении высоты/ширины ячейки меняется каждая таблица. Вот Таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо сделать что-то вроде такого на одном листе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка или столбец не разбиваются на несколько. Но если в одном месте объединить, например, 2 ячейки в строке (получится один "столбец" из двух), то в другом 2 столбца останутся.

Вариант1. Создать основную таблицу, оставив строки для создания верхних текстов и таблицы. Потом погонять верхнюю таблицу: выделить несколько ячеек, закладка *Главная-Выравнивание-Объединить*.

Вариант2. Несколько сложнее: продумать размещение таблиц, в нужных местах оставлять по несколько столбцов разной ширины для объединения ячеек (например, 4 столбца: в одной строке объединить 1-2, в другой 1-3, еще в одной 2-4).

Вариант 3. В сети есть множество бланков с такой реализацией: ширина столбцов задается по размеру наименьшей ячейки, а потом - кропотливая работа по формированию ячеек таблиц.

*Excel* не *Word* и форматирование текстов и таблиц в нем сильно ограничено. Для создания бланков лучше использовать *Word*. Если в планах - автозаполнение бланков, то в связке *Excel-Word* это реализуемо с помощью макросов. Это самый оптимальный вариант для автообработки.